# Как реализовать данную анимацию?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, navigation

Смысл в том, чтобы при наведении на число - оно отдалялось от других, но есть вот пару проблем:
Я попробовал пару подходов, через псевдоэлементы и без них.
Проблема у первого в том, что я не знаю с какой стороны подойти к изменению положения блока, который нужно отодвигать от остальных, да и сами псевдоэлементы, вероятно, это не лучшее решение, так как ::before не растёт вверх от элемента.
Второй подход вероятно слишком "быдлокодерский" и я не могу через jQuery обратиться именно к нужному родителю, чтобы он добавил класс своему потомку который я указал.

Вот изображение с примером такого меню:

[image: Пример реализуемого меню]

https://codepen.io/4rmr3d1/pen/MWWjWXj

```html
    <nav id="" class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>01</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>02</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>03</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>04</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <nav class="nav">
      <div class="nav-item">
        <div class="nav-item__line"></div>
        <div class="nav-item__number">01</div>
        <div class="nav-item__line"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-item">
        <div class="nav-item__line"></div>
        <div class="nav-item__number">02</div>
        <div class="nav-item__line"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-item">
        <div class="nav-item__line"></div>
        <div class="nav-item__number">03</div>
        <div class="nav-item__line"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-item">
        <div class="nav-item__line"></div>
        <div class="nav-item__number">04</div>
        <div class="nav-item__line"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

```
        .navigation {
        font-size: 30px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 20%;
        left: 25%;
        ul{
            list-style: none;
            text-align: center;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column wrap;
            padding-inline-start: 0;
            .active{
                transform: translateY(-50px);      
            }
            li{
                flex: 0 0 auto;
                justify-self: center;
                transition: .5s ease-in-out;
                .nav-item{

                }
                &:not(:last-child):after{
                    content: '';
                    position: absolute;
                    left:50%;
                    height: 0;
                    width: 1px;
                    background-color: black;
                    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
                }
                &:not(:first-child):before{
                    content: '';
                    position: absolute;
                    left:50%;
                    height: 0;
                    width: 1px;
                    background-color: black;
                    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
                }
                &:hover::after{
                    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
                    height: 50px
                }
                &:hover::before{
                    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
                    height: 50px
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .nav {
      font-size: 30px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 25%;
      right: 25%;
      &-item{
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column wrap;
        align-items: center;
        .active{
          height: 50px;
        }
        &__line{
          width: 1px;
          height: 0;
          background-color: black;
          transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        }
        &__number{
        }
      }
    }
```

```
    $(function () {
        $('body').on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            }
        }, '.navigation ul li');
    });

    $(function () {
        $('body').on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $('.nav-item__line').addClass('active');
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $('.nav-item__line').removeClass('active');
            }
        }, '.nav-item');
    });
```

Comment: можете добавить изображения до и после наведения?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ добавил.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я бы сделал это за счет бордеров, например так:

```css
div.expand {
  font-size: 20px;
  display:block;
  width: 20px;
  cursor:default;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width:40px;
  text-align:center;
}

div.expand:before, div.expand:after {
  content: '';
  border: 0px solid black;
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-left:20px;
}
div.expand:hover{
  font-size:40px
}

div.expand:not(:first-child):hover:before {
  border-top: 50px solid black;
}

div.expand:not(:last-child):hover:after {
  border-top: 50px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class=expand>01</div>
  <div class=expand>02</div>
  <div class=expand>03</div>
  <div class=expand>04</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @4rmr3d1 можно испоьзовать :focus, или использовать порсто добавление произвольного стиля, а не :hover

Comment: Максимум, чего бы я подправил, это margin у псевдоэлемента поставил auto для центрирования бордера, а кто кажется 20px - это немного костыльно, ну зависит именно от величины шрифта.

Comment: @4rmr3d1 у родительского элемента ширина 40 и центровка текста, но можно как Вам угодно =)